# Passing model with dependencies to rest api service

Tags: c#, rest, design-patterns, asp.net-web-api, restful-architecture

What's the "good practice" for RESTful api service when I want to pass model which has references to another model? Like:

```
class ClassModel
{
int Id
int Number
List<StudentModel> Students
}

class StudentModel
{
int Id
string Name
string Surname
ClassModel CurrentClass
}
```

and while creating new student: `POST .../api/students/`
should I pass in `StudentModel` object entire `ClassModel` associated object or only class `Id` and get this object on service side?

Answer (score 0):

the best practice would be to pass only the data you need for whatever operation you're trying to perform.

If you try to follow standards then you really should use POST to create new data and PUT to update.

Now, how you work with your data depends on your business rules. At first look I'd say this :

if you want to create a student then only use the data required for that initial registration ... name, contact information, address, whatever you need.
Then you would have something like EnrollStudentInClass and that's where you perform the link. If all this call done is a linking operation then you don't need to pass the entire data graph of the class, just the data you need to uniquely identify the class you are after, in this case, the Id.

This helps keep things nicely separated. However if you have a business requirement which says that you cannot create a student without enrolling them into at least a class then you would pass the classes information as well and do all that in one call.

The most important thing here though is to keep it as simple as you can and don't try to do too much in one go unless you really need to.

Comment: switch that around. Post insert, put update. which also goes to show the primarily opinion-based nature of the question

Comment: @Nkosi I don't see that `POST` *as insert* could be an opinion... It's the de facto standard in RESTful API design. Also, `PUT`/`PATCH` are updates...

Answer (score 0):

When creating an student, any associated resource within itself will be given as a *reference*, because you won't use the resource to create students to also create classes.

- `POST /students` will create students.
- `POST /classes` will create classes.

If you want to create an student and associate it to an existing class, you may send a request to `/students` using `POST` verb and its entity would look as follows:

```
{ "name": "Matías", "surname": "Fidemraizer", "class": { "id": 38 } }
```

In the other hand, if you need to create a class, you'll send a `POST` request to `/classes` which will receive a response with `201 Created` status code and it will also come with a `Location` header containing the resource URI that was created (f.e. `Location: /classes/2`).

Probably you should design your models and services to avoid having to load associations and work with *references*,  because even your business layer shouldn't need to load the class to associate it to a given student.

Furthermore, your `ClassModel` could provide a `Load` method to load the entire model, and this will be too easy because you just need to get the model by its identifier and fill the rest of properties in the whole class!